# How do I test code inside ".subscribe()" Angular/Jasmine

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, subscribe

I have this Code in my `StatisticComponent`

```
this.subscription = this.locationService.getStatisticOne(this.formService.getFormValue())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.array = data;
    this.wrongValueOne = this.array.shift();
    for (let array of this.array) {
      this.addData(this.myChartOne, array.date, array.leistung);
    }
  });
```

Now I want to write a Test to see if anything inside this `.subscribe()` function is being called or executed. This code snippet is being executed inside a `generateStatisticOne()` function which is called in a `getData()` function which is called in `ngOnInit()` or at a button press. The problem is that im new to writing tests and don't even know if what I've found here makes even sense, but I have this code for the test for now

```
describe('StatisticComponent', () => {
  let component: StatisticComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StatisticComponent>;

  const locationServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('LocationService', {
    getStatisticOne: of([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }])
  });


  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [StatisticComponent],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [{ provide: LocationService, useValue: locationServiceSpy },
        LocationService,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StatisticComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    locationService = TestBed.get(LocationService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call array.shift ', fakeAsync(() => {
    const service = TestBed.get(LocationService); // get your service
    spyOn(service, 'getStatisticOne').and.callThrough(); // create spy
    spyOn(Array.prototype, 'shift');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(Array.prototype.shift).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

The error I get when running the code is "expected spy shift to have been called"

Comment: For one, you can try to adjust your spy on `shift` (`spyOn(Array.prototype, 'shift').and.callThrough();` but a better idea would be to check the expected *outcome* of your `subscribe` callback. You should check that `array` and `wrongValueOne` are equal to your expectation.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but the expected outcome never happens as the changes seem to get lost after the subscribe method is done. I pull the data with subscribe and add it to a chart from chart.js. if you might have an idea how to check that outcome I'd be glad, but `wrongValueOne` and `array` cant be tested like that (or I'm missing something big)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to split your testing into two. The first set of tests will instantiate the Service and mock the HttpClient using the HttpClientTestingModule, and the second set of tests will instantiate the component and mock the Service. That way you get a clean separation between what is being tested and where it's boundaries lie.
To answer your question of how to test the subscribe method, once you have the Service mocked, you can respond to the method call using `of()` from the rxjs observable library, and within there you can mock the data up to look however you want.